# How to draw inside layer's mask?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

[image]

I am using the following code to produce this (inside drawRect):

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addArc(center: self.circleCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: 2 * 3.14, clockwise: false)

let whitePath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: path)
UIColor.white.setStroke()
whitePath.lineWidth = 3
whitePath.stroke()


path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))

let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
maskLayer.path = path
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

layer.mask = maskLayer
```

However, I would like to white-out the top part of the circle, so that the entire circle is white inside, but I am unsure of how to do this, because I have already set my `layer.mask` to be the CAShape Layer, so any drawing I do inside this circle does not show up.

The mask needs to be a circle, because actually for most of my use cases, for this custom UIView, it does not clip the top of another view, so using a circle works well. How can I draw over the top area of the circle?

Edit: I want this part (where I circled in red) to be filled white:

[image]

So I want the final image to look like (sorry for bad quality, manually drew this on my iPad):

[image]

Comment: As a general rule, manipulating layers in `drawRect` is not advisable, as it occurs too late in the rendering cycle. If you want to add a mask, do that in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Completely unrelated, rather than typing `3.14`, I'd suggest using `.pi`. Also, I'm not sure why you're creating `CGMutablePath` rather than just creating `UIBezierPath` directly.

Comment: sorry, maybe my wording was confusing. I have gone back and added additional photos to show exactly what I want. And I am using CGPath because layer.mask takes a CGPath, not UIBezierPath.

Comment: yes correct, the "Messaging" is from a view underneath. The dark shadow view is a UIView on top, and I have a mask in the dark shadow view so I can see through underneath it. As far as I know, if you want to "cut a hole" in a UIView, as I am doing, you need to use a mask (unless there is another method I'm not aware of)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said:

> ... the "Messaging" is from a view underneath. The dark shadow view is a UIView on top, and I have a mask in the dark shadow view so I can see through underneath it.

Here are two approaches:

1. If you really want to use masks, you need a complicated view hierarchy that has four main views: The root view (white), the chrome view (the view with all the chrome that will be masked when you add your circle mask; e.g. that top part of your circle that you need masked out), the UI element view(s) that will not be masked when you add your masks to the chrome and the dimming view), and the dimming view (which will also get masked). These latter three need to be subviews of the main view (don't put the messages button on the chrome view, but make it its own view, so when you mask the chrome out, these UI elements won't get masked out).

   You end up with something like the following (this is showing after the masks have been added):

   [image]

   You can then make dimming view visible and mask it and the background view:

   ```
   @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
       dimmingView.alpha = 0.5
       let center = messagingView.center
       let radius = messagingView.frame.width * 0.7

       mask(center: center, radius: radius, in: messagingView.superview!, on: dimmingView)
       mask(center: center, radius: radius, in: messagingView.superview!, on: backgroundView)
   }

   private func mask(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, in view: UIView, on viewToMask: UIView) {
       let point = view.convert(center, to: viewToMask)
       let path = UIBezierPath(rect: viewToMask.bounds)
       path.addArc(withCenter: point, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)
       let mask = CAShapeLayer()
       mask.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
       mask.path = path.cgPath
       mask.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
       viewToMask.layer.mask = mask
   }
   ```

   Thus with the dimming view not visible and no masks in place, you have the before view:

   [image]

   And then after the dimming view is made visible and both it and the "chrome" view are masked:

   [image]
2. Easier, IMHO, would be to:

   - take snapshot of messages view;
   - add dimming view (obscuring the messages view);
   - add circle view (opaque and white) on top of the dimming view; and
   - add snapshot (or another rendition) of messages view on top of the circle.

   This will yield an effect of feeling like you're "revealing" the messages button, but what you're really doing is adding your dimming view, a circle, and another rendition of the messages button. This avoids all of the clumsiness of adding of masks to various views.

Answer (score 1):

A mask doesn't draw, it masks. If you want to force part of your circle to white, you need to draw in white. If you're overriding drawRect, just draw the area you want to be white after drawing your image.

If you wanted to create a view that did what you wanted without overriding drawRect, which is often a better way to go, you'd set up a mask layer on your view's layer, plus add another shape layer on top of your image view that contained your white shape.